How to Call API without open app when user click action from interactive notification?
I'm building app using expo, and integrated notification using expo-notification.
Also, I made the interactive notification using setNotificationCategoryAsync.
I added postpone action to action of notification, and I want to send postpone event to server side.
Please explain how can we do it with expo. if impossible with expo, native solution that using objective-c also good for me.
